# Bind text to a global function

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0, knockout-3.2

Trying to bind `text` to a global function outside the viewmodel throws the following error:

> knockout.js:60 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return names }"
>   Message: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return myFunction($data) }"
>   Message: myFunction is not defined

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/1hz10pkc/)

HTML

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: names">
    <li data-bind="text: myFunction($data)"></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
function myFunction(text){
    return text + '--';
}

function demoViewModel() {
    self.names = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

    return self;
}

var mm = new demoViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(mm);
```

Instead, if I extend `String` object and apply the function in the following way, it works as expected:

```
<li data-bind="text: $data.myFunction()"></li>
```

Extending String object:

```
String.prototype.myFunction = function(){
    return this + '--';
}
```

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/1hz10pkc/1/)

Why is this? Isn't there a better way to apply a global function to a `text` binding?

Comment: Not really related to your question, but note that you're missing `var self = this` on your demoVM; you're actually using the global [window.self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) object as your VM right now.

Comment: Explicitly adding it to the global context by using `window.myFunction` should work, right? https://jsfiddle.net/2prmfwyx/ Have a look at how knockout's `bindingContext` works and its internal use of the `with` keyword via `with($data || {})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reference your function from your knockout templates, it needs to be attached to a ViewModel.  In the simple case above, you can just attach it to `demoViewModel` and reference it in your template directly:

```js
function myFunction(text){
    return text + '--';
}

function demoViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.names = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    self.myFunction = myFunction;

    return self;
}

ko.applyBindings(new demoViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: names">
    <li data-bind="text: myFunction($data)"></li>
</ul>
```

This isn't really a "global" function, it's just a standard viewModel property and if you ended up with nested binding contexts you'd have to do `$parents[n].myFunction` or, if you've attached it to your root viewModel, you could do `$root.myFunction`.

---

Another way to handle this is to add the function to the [binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) directly.  This allows it to be referenced regardless of what the current viewModel is.

The "as" option on "foreach" binding handlers and template binding handlers is one way of adding things to the binding context; but I use a "let" bindingHandler for this purpose, the let bindingHandler isn't an official part of KO, but is [often recommended](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1002#issuecomment-19361275) by Michael Best, one of the core contributors.

```js
function myFunction(text){
    return text + '--';
}

function demoViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.names = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    self.myFunction = myFunction;

    return self;
}


//Let binding Handler
ko.bindingHandlers['let'] = {
    'init': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // Make a modified binding context, with extra properties, and apply it to descendant elements
        var innerContext = bindingContext.extend(valueAccessor());
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerContext, element);

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings['let'] = true;

ko.applyBindings(new demoViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko let: {
    myFunction: myFunction
} -->
  <ul data-bind="foreach: {
      data: names,
      at: 'name'
  }">
      <li data-bind="text: myFunction($data)"></li>
  </ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```

In the above example, you can reference `myFunction` anywhere within the `let` binding, regardless of how many levels deep of viewModels you are.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion to do what you want . Your Function is not defined in that scope. Here you actually bind each name (even it can be an object) to your function outside the view model 
Example :https://jsfiddle.net/1hz10pkc/2/ 

HTML :

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: names">
    <li data-bind="text:name "></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
var myFunction = function(text){
  var self = this;
  self.name = text + "--" ; 
}

function demoViewModel() {
   var self = this;
   var arr =  ['a', 'b', 'c'];
   self.names = ko.observableArray($.map(arr, function (element) {
        return new myFunction(element);
    }));
}
var mm = new demoViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(mm);
```

Comment: But I don't really want to modify the original value. I would therefore have to create a new variable with your suggestion.

Comment: I gave my own answer, but this answer is really good, too.  Really it's often better to try to do as much logic in the ViewModel and not in the templates.

Comment: Note you can just do `arr.map`, the only real benefit of using `$.map` is if you're trying to support IE8.

Comment: @Alvaro in this https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/229/  example you can define  a computed observable bind to the `name` `observable` so whenever `name observable` gets changed ,computed variable gets updated too.

Comment: @Retsam I always use `$.map` as you mentioned to support `IE8` just in case if anyone still is using it.